# oracle sql creating combinations same table without repeat

Tags: sql, oracle, cartesian

How I can solve this?
I need to eliminate the duplicated of the Cartesian product, of a table with itself.
I thought of using "connect by". Thanks.

```
create table foo (
num number(2)
);

insert into foo values (1);
insert into foo values (2);
insert into foo values (3);

select a.num,b.num
from foo a, foo b;

NUM NUM
--- ---
 1   1 
 1   2 
 1   3 
 2   1 * duplicated
 2   2 
 2   3 
 3   1 * duplicated
 3   2 * duplicated
 3   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select a.num,b.num
  from foo a cross join foo b
 where a.num <= b.num
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.num,b.num
from foo a, foo b
where a.num = b.num
```

Comment: Stop promoting comma seperate JOINS!

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01f4a/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table foo ( num ) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select a.num,b.num
from foo a CROSS JOIN foo b
WHERE a.num <= b.num
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01f4a/2/0)**:

```
| NUM | NUM |
|-----|-----|
|   1 |   1 |
|   1 |   2 |
|   1 |   3 |
|   2 |   2 |
|   2 |   3 |
|   3 |   3 |
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a cross join, since you're doing a join where you want to match rows from the second instance of the table that have the same or greater number than the number from the first instance of the table. That's how you'll prevent the "duplicate" entries:

```
with foo as (SELECT LEVEL num FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3)
select f1.num f1_num,
       f2.num f2_num
from   foo f1
       join foo f2 on (f1.num <= f2.num);

    F1_NUM     F2_NUM
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3
         2          2
         2          3
         3          3
```